# unable to install PunJab

Tags: python, xmpp

I am unable to install [PunJab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab) on my system.

> PunJab is a HTTP jabber client
>   interface. It is a BOSH connection
>   manager that allows persistent client
>   connections to a XMPP server.

When I type the following command

> python setup.py install

It says invalid syntax error.. I have python 2.7 and twisted python 10.2 running on windows XP.I have set the environment variables for python...

What have I done wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

wat the heck is punjab?? I have no clue what it is.. But anyways when you add it to your system path it doesnt become part of your system path immediately.. A restart is normally required.

Instead what I would suggest is go to your python install directory and find the executable or python script that  is needed to run this program and go to the command prompt and run it with your file name.

Going to Cmd prompt: Start -> Run -> type cmd and Enter

A black box should appear and now type the executable full path that you need to use like 
    C:\Python27\python.exe  "location of your file"

thus your command should look like
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:\users\kavya\Desktop\Punjab.py

Well hope that helps and please let me know wat the heck is Punjab and I know u r nt talking abt the state..

Comment: well..In order to use xmpp(IM protocol)in web applications you need punjab which  is a standalone connection manager.It turns stateless http requests to stateful xmpp connections... To run PUNJAB u ll need twistd python and python...yes i did restart my system...acc to the document i have to run the command python setup.py install to install punjab....:which is where i am stuck...

Comment: also you might be missing sm parameters it requires.. check out the punjab FAQ ABT INSTALLATION errors..

Comment: no it din work... also it says twistd is not recognised as aninternal or external command...

Comment: that looks like a python error.. something wrong with the way u r installing i guess.. doesnt punjab hv a forum of its own.. u should flag it there..

Comment: i downloaded python 2.7 msi and twisted python 10.2 msi...installed python then twisted...set up user variable PYTHON_HOME=C:\Python27..then in cmd tried echo %PYTHON_HOME% later cd %PYTHON_HOME% then i ran python cmd...al this worked fine..hav'nt found forum for this...

Comment: hmmm....i don hav any idea abt python..jst needed this to install punjab...ll do little bit of searching then put up the question if i am nt able to trouble shoot